# "await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);" does not return anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

this line of code does not return any result

```
GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

I have found the service by this method

```
GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid("00001805-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"),BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);
```

and characterstic by this

```
 var result = await attributeInfoDisp.service.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid("00002A2B-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"), BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);
```

and descriptor by this

```
var result = await selectedCharacteristic.GetDescriptorsForUuidAsync(new Guid("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"), BluetoothCacheMode.Cached);
```

but when i try to read the characterstics using

```
GattReadResult result = await selectedCharacteristic.ReadValueAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

i get null result

How can I read the characterstics?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is your characteristic readable? By some reason it also may not work with BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached. Try to use BluetoothCacheMode.Cached.

Comment: I used BluetoothCacheMode.Cached. I am reading health thermometer service and its characterstics and I have set read property as true and mandatory,but still it says read failed

Comment: Have you set application capabilities? (https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-device-capabilities-for-bluetooth)

Comment: I added this code to my package.appxmanifest   <!--BT_Code: Always declare the bluetooth capability when using Bluetooth-->
    <DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth.genericAttributeProfile">
       <Device Id="any">
          <Function Type="name:healthThermometer" />
       </Device>
    </DeviceCapability>   
  </Capabilities>   But still no luck ,it cannot read temperature

Comment: Your code looks correct. There are 2 possible issues: bung in WinRT API ( guess you use Windows) or bug in your device. If you have Android smartphone can you run any BLE app on it and make sure it can read the value as expected?